# CORS policy defined in next.config.js doesn't seem to be applied to API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js, cors

I have a Next.js app with the following structure:

```
.
├── next.config.js
└── src /
    └── app/
        ├── page.tsx
        └── getYoutubeTranscript/
            └── getYoutubeTranscript.tsx
```

`next.config.js` has the following policy defined:

```
// @ts-check
 
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    async headers() {
        return [
            {
                // matching all API routes
                source: "/api/:path*",
                headers: [
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" }, //http://localhost:3000
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT" },
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

`page.tsx` is a client component that uses the `getYoutubeTranscript` server component to fetch a Youtube transcript. But when this code executes I get the client-side error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<ID>' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Looks like I misconfigured CORS in `next.config.js` -- any tips here to further diagnose?

---

**Update #1:** I don't see a Host listed in the Request Headers of my call from Developer Console? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59353387/3899919) implies when Host != Origin that causes the error

[image]

**Update #2**: Here are the Response Headers (two images):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Post what the preflight OPTIONS call returns

Comment: Thanks for the q -- I edit my post to show the Request Headers of my call

Comment: If that's a request to youtube from your browser you're going to be out of luck.  It's youtube that needs to add those headers.  CORS is just a system that the browser respects dictated by the endpoint.  Since you're using Next, you may have intended to proxy it through an `/api` endpoint you host, but it is hitting youtube directly, so in that case you'll want to modify the frontend call to call your Next API endpoint

Comment: Ok sounds like I should look into setting up a Next API endpoint :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood CORS. You try to fetch some youtube URLs from localhost (with xhr I assume) which YOUTUBE doesn't allow with its CORS. Changing your own API CORS will allow other sites to fetch from your API

I also have a couple of notes on the question/update:

1. When asked what OPTIONS **returns**, we need the response, not the request
2. You added some CORS config to an `/api/` path but I can't see any in your screenshot of the structure.

Now, guessing a bit here since I can't be sure of what happens here, if you want to fetch a youtube video in your NextJS app, you need to fetch it FROM an API or a server component.

Anyways... You say that the `getYoutubeTranscript` is a server component and it fetches from youtube so I also think there is an error in the definition here somewhere since, if it was, you wouldn't have any CORS issues. I guess a missing `'use server'` somewhere...

My 2 cents on an alternative: As a rule, I never change my `page.tsx` to client components so that I can always fetch the necessary data there.

Final note: As far as I know, you are not allowed to fetch `youtube.com/watch` URLs only the embedded ones. Youtube videos will actually not play if not on their domains. But I may be mistaken here...

Comment: Thank you!

- I've added the Response Headers 

- If I change the config to `source: "/getVideo/getYoutubeTranscript",` it produces the same error 

- Well, my `page.tsx` takes in user input for the Youtube video, so it would have to be a Client component 

- Yeah, I got the Youtube transcript fetch to work in a Colab, so I assumed it would work on my app ... if it doesn't, why does https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-transcript exist at all?